# $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0, 1)$, $Y \sim \mathcal{N}(0, 2)$, show $P(X \in A \cap [-M, M]^c) \leq P(Y \in A \cap [-M, M]^c)$.

Tags: probability

Let $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0, 1)$ and $Y \sim \mathcal{N}(0, 2)$. Show that for any measurable $A$ and any $M > 0$ 
$$
P(X \in A \cap [-M, M]^c) \leq P(Y \in A \cap [-M, M]^c).
$$

**Attempt:**

I don't see much way out other than arguing based on the integrals that define the probabilities. We have
$$
P(X \in A \cap [-M, M]^c) = \int_\mathbb{R} 1_{A \cap [-M, M]^c}(x) \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\frac{x^2}{2}} \, \mathrm{d}x .
$$

It is clear that $e^{\frac{x^2}{2}} \leq e^{\frac{x^2}{4}}$ but $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \geq \frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}}$ so I cannot simply apply monotonicity of integrals to finish. How do I proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X \sim \mathcal N(0,1), Y \sim \mathcal N(0,2)$. Take any $A \in \mathcal B(\mathbb R), M \in \mathbb R_+$. Since both density functions are even, and due to $M>0$ we can consider only the case, where $\forall_{x \in A} : x>0$. So WLOG: $A \in \mathcal B(\mathbb R_+)$

As you stated:

$$\mathbb P( X \in A \cap [-M,M]^c) = \int_{A \cap (M,+\infty)} \frac{1}{\sqrt2 \pi}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} dx $$

And

$$ \mathbb P(Y \in A \cap [-M,M]^c) = \int_{A \cap (M,+\infty)} \frac{1}{2\pi}e^{-\frac{x^2}{4}} dx$$
Substituting $ t= \frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}$, we have $dt = \frac{dx}{\sqrt2}$. Looking at the set we integrate over: $B \cap (\frac{M}{\sqrt{2}},+\infty)$, where $B = \{ \frac{x}{\sqrt{2}} : x \in A \}$. We get:

$\mathbb P(Y \in A \cap [-M,M]^c) = \int_{B \cap (\frac{M}{\sqrt{2}},+\infty)} \frac{1}{\sqrt2 \pi}e^\frac{-t^2}{2} dt$

Now, we have the same function under integral sign. Obviously $ (\frac{M}{\sqrt2}, +\infty) \subset (M, +\infty)$. Now examine function (say $f$)  $ t \to e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}$. It is increasing on $(0,+\infty)$, so for any $y \in A$ for which we have $\frac{y}{\sqrt2} \in B$, we have $f(y) \leq f(\frac{y}{\sqrt2})$. Note that it is important we intersect $B$ with set $(\frac{M}{\sqrt2},+\infty)$ and not $(M,+\infty)$, because we can guarantee then that for $y \in A \cap (M,+\infty)$ we have $\frac{y}{2} \in B \cap (\frac{M}{\sqrt2},+\infty)$. So in both cases we integrate the same (positive) function, but in the second case the values our function attains aren't less. So

$$ \int_{B \cap (\frac{M}{\sqrt{2}},+\infty)} \frac{1}{\sqrt2 \pi}e^\frac{-t^2}{2} dt \ge \int_{A \cap (M,+\infty)} \frac{1}{\sqrt2 \pi}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} dx $$

And that means

$$ \mathbb P(X \in A \cap [-M,M]^c) \le \mathbb P(Y \in A \cap [-M,M]^c)$$